# Jenkins credential scope missing

Tags: jenkins

When I add credentials, I can not choose the scope (Global, System) of credentials in Jenkins and can not proceed the Jenkins job without add credentials please help. How should I solve this issue?

Credential scope not showing see the screenshot.

[image]

```
Error while serving http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:xxxx/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope.
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:745)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:490)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:799)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the scope parameter of the constructor public com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:801)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.access$200(RequestImpl.java:85)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:690)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate interface com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this one too.

I’m adding a comment here as I am running ad-guard on my mac

Turning this off, allowed Jenkins to work

Basically the reverse proxy in Ad-Guard was breaking it

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would not have easily figured out what the issue was without your answer.

Comment: This worked thanks. I removed my Adblocker chrome extension and it worked

Answer (score 1):

one of the reasons could be this

If you are using Jenkins front-end through reverse proxy it may block some of Jenkins's XHRs. which may enough to break the UI.

Comment: So how can I solve that…?? Can you say some way to solve that..??

Comment: You may use configuring nginx for Jenkins as reverse proxy steps mentioned in documentation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins
Similar issue link at https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/issues/607